# Is the new MongoDB Timeseries Collection supported by mathematica?

Tags: mongodb

Is the new MongoDB Timeseries Collection supported by Mathematica?

Will I be able to read and write to a MongoDB using the `MongoLink` framework

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries-collections/

Comment: It seems like you could try it out and see, if you have access to those data formats.

Comment: I have done that and while is appears to work, I am unable to see any performance benefits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be supported. Here is my exploratory work.

Create sample data:

```
start = Now;
numberOfDataPoints = 100000;

dates = DateObject /@ (AbsoluteTime[DateObject[start, "Minute"]] - 
       Range[60, numberOfDataPoints*60, 60]); // AbsoluteTiming;
data = RandomInteger[100, numberOfDataPoints];

dataset = MapThread[Association["Date" -> #1, "Data" -> #2] &, {dates, data}];
```

Upload to our premade collections `regularCollection` and `timeSeriesCollection`

```
MongoCollectionInsert[regularCollection, dataset]; // AbsoluteTiming (*33.416*)
MongoCollectionInsert[timeSeriesCollection, dataset]; // AbsoluteTiming (*34.797*)
```

In this example I could not see any performance difference in the data upload (ie `MongoCollectionInsert`) or querying using `MongoCollectionFind`:

```
MongoCollectionFind[
    regularCollection, 
    <|
      "Date" -> 
       dates[[Round[numberOfDataPoints/2]]]
    |>
    ]; // RepeatedTiming (* 0.000332552 *)

MongoCollectionFind[
    timeSeriesCollection, 
    <|
      "Date" -> 
       dates[[Round[numberOfDataPoints/2]]]
    |>
    ]; // RepeatedTiming (* 0.000337617 *)
```

however when we look at the `MongoCollectionStats` we can see that the space saving benefits of the timeseries collection:

```
MongoCollectionStats[regularCollection]["storageSize"] (* 2473984 *)
MongoCollectionStats[timeSeriesCollection]["storageSize"] (* 884736 *)
```